# How to do a basic proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$; let $C$, $D \subseteq B$ such that $C\subseteq D$. Prove that 
$$f^{-1}(C) \subseteq f^{-1}(D)$$

*Work done*:

$x \in f^{-1}(C)= \{x\in A \ \text{such that} \ f(x) \in C\}$;

$x \in f^{-1}(D)= \{x\in A \ \text{such that} \ f(x) \in D\}$,

but $f(x) \in C \implies f(x) \in D$,

therefore we have: $x \in f^{-1}(C)= \{x\in A \ \text{such that} \ f(x) \in D\}$,

which implies that $x \in f^{-1}(D)= \{x\in A \ \text{such that} \ f(x) \in D\}$.

So, because every element of $f^{-1}(C)$ is an element of $f^{-1}(D)$, the relation $f^{-1}(C) \subseteq f^{-1}(D)$ is proved. Is this correct?

Comment: How would you prove that a set is a subset of some other set?

Comment: How far have you gotten with this question?

Comment: @John question edited

Comment: @John, but I don't know if my work is formal enough

Comment: @user179760 This is a better question after having shown what you've done.  We can work with this better, and it indicates explicitly that you're not just posting a problem and expecting us to solve it for you.  Welcome to Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would like to point out - which you might probably be clear about - is that the notation $f^{-1}(B)$ here has nothing to do with the inverse function. It is as you have stated the set of all $x \in A$ such that $f(x) \in B$. Now,

$$ x \in f^{-1} (C) \implies f(x) \in C \implies f(x) \in D $$

You've gotten this far. Now look at the definition for $ f^{-1}(D) = \{x \ | \ \color {olive}{f(x) \in D}\} $. We have concluded that $\color {olive}{f(x) \in D}$. So $x \in  \;$ **???**

And you chose $x$ arbitrarily. So if you have proven that $ x \in P \implies x \in Q $ then you have  proven $P \subseteq Q$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question. Can you check if the whole reasoning is correct?

Comment: @user179760: Yes. Looks correct. Although you could economise in the writing a bit more. One more thing if I'm not wrong, in situations like these I think it is recommended to write your own answer. But this might take a trip to meta to confirm. But your proof is fine.